# the slider will not change the figures

Tags: python, bokeh

i use bokeh to create a figure with sliders, but the sliders will not refresh the figure

i have create a dataframe like this

```
month = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
tilts = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
data = [0.1,0.2,0.3,1,2,3,11,12,13,21,22,24]
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':month,'tilt':tilts,'data'=data})

df_default = df[df['tilt']==1]

source = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': df_default.month.tolist(), 
    'y': df_default.ac_monthly.tolist(), 
})

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    tilt = slider.value
    df_new = df[df['tilt']==tilt]
    new_data = {
        'x': df_new.month.tolist(), 
        'y': df_new.ac_monthly.tolist(), 
    }
    source.data = new_data

slider = Slider(start=1, end=4, step=1, value=1, title='tilt')
slider.on_change('value',update_plot)

layout = row(
    plot,
    column(slider)
)

output_file("slider.html", title="slider.py example")

show(layout)
```

And this can give me the figures, but no matter how i change the number of the slider , the figure will not refresh

Comment: sorry , the 'ac_monthly' should be the 'data'

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting a loud warning printed when you run this code, are you not seeing one? Real Python callbacks, with `on_change` ***only work with the Bokeh server***. (The Bokeh server is exactly the Python process that actually runs your callback code) What you are doing here with `show`  and `output_file` is generating a [standalone, static HTML output](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#standalone-documents), that has no connection to any Python process after it is saved, and no ability to run real Python callbacks.

For standalone HTML output, all you can use are [javascript callbacks](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#userguide-interaction-jscallbacks), for example with `CustomJS`:

```
slider.js_on_change('value', CustomJS(code="""
    // only JavaScript code here
    console.log(value)
"""))
```

If you want to run real Python callbacks, e.g. to use real Pandas or Numpy code, etc., you will need to run a Bokeh Server Application. You can read all about those in the [Running a Bokeh Server](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) chapter of the docs.

Comment: Thank you so much! But the reason why i use the python to create a function is that i have no knowledge of the Javascript. So i really do not know how to do that. I will try to use the javascript right now./

Comment: i change the part you said into this, and right now there is no warming , but still not working         callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var tilt = slider.value;
    var x = data['x']
    var y = data['y']
    'x'        = df[df['tilt']==tilt].month;
    'y'        = df[df['tilt']==tilt].ac_monthly;
    plot.line(x='x', y='y', source=source, size=12, alpha=0.7, 
         );
    }
    source.change.emit();
""")
    
slider = Slider(start=1, end=4, step=1, value=1, title='tilt')
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

Comment: Pandas Dataframes do not exist in the browser. They are Python objects. To use them, you will have to run a Bokeh server application.